My samba refuses to write as an authorised user on any device except main machine
I tried installing, reinstalling, following the official ubuntu tutorial, and other tutorials, and yet I can only access the shares from a Windows machine and an iPhone as a read-only. I don’t know what to give exactly, but please do tell me and i’ll edit this post to give info. Any help is appreciated, thank you.
